# How to edit files in Azure App Service when continuous deployment is enabled

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service app that has continuous deployment from Azure DevOps enabled.

When I try to use the App Service Editor to change a file, such as a configuration file, I get an error saying that the edits cannot be saved.  I also see a warning saying "Continuous deployment may be enabled".

[image: Failed to save]

How can manual changes be made to files in an Azure App Service when continuous deployment is enabled?

Comment: If you want to use the online code editor, you can temporarily disable continuous deployment.Once disable the Continuos deployment , make your changes and again enable and check once.

Comment: If you want to use the online code editor, you can temporarily disable continuous deployment.Once disable the Continuos deployment , make your changes again enable and check once.

Comment: I can't find a way to "temporarily disable" the deployment.  It can be disconnected, but that is quite a drastic change.   Also, disconnecting it does let me edit files using the App Service Editor.  I still see errors when trying to save any edits.

Comment: Please refer [Warning in Continuous Deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/App-Service-Editor#continuous-deployment)

Comment: This says: "Any changes that you make will be reflected in the running site, but any future deployments will overwrite your changes."  However, my problem is that I am unable to make any changes.  Instead, I get the error shown in the image! :(

Comment: Please have a look at [Enabling Continuous Integration](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/azuredevops/continuousintegration/) once.

Comment: That link shows how to set up Azure DevOps.  I don't think it shows how to make changes in Azure App Service, right?

Comment: In Task 3: Invoking a continuous integration build - Check 3 and 4 points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241238/discussion-between-sean-kearon-and-harshithaveeramalla-mt).

Comment: Any update regarding the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

you can definately make changes.

there are so majorly 2 ways you can do it using cli (I prefer) or text editor in your service.

Here is how you can make changes.

open new tab and copy this https://Your-apps-service.scm.azurewebsites.net/webssh/host url

> REPLACE Your-apps-service with your app service URL

navigate to your application folder `cd site/wwwroot` unless, server is set manually or something

then navigate to folder and edit file in vi text editor.

save changes and restart server (app service) !

Comment: Yes, the settings can be changed, but that isn't editing the files (such as app.config, etc.).

Comment: I edited the answer follow the steps, you can change anything. @SeanKearon